# get reference to current InteractiveShell instance in IPython (trying to hook %exit)

Tags: ipython

I'd like to create a hook in IPython that runs when i do Cntl-D, %Exit, %Quit, or %exit and %quit and confirm.

The motivation is that i want to have a thread that runs in IPython indefinitely in the background until i press Cntl-D to exit, and then i want to tell that thread to quit. I figure that i will use the hook to send a signal to my background thread.

I figure one way to do this would be to wrap IPython::iplib::InteractiveShell::exit. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do what i am trying to do? thanks

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to tell your thread to exit is probably to register an [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) handler. That's a standard Python thing, that doesn't depend on IPython.

If you want a reference to the InteratctiveShell object, in IPython 0.11+ use `get_ipython()`. I think you're using an older version, though; try `_ip`.